# Getting datetime field from a database

Tags: mysql

I have one rare problem.
I use this query to extract a date and time

```
$datum_query = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM datetime) AS dan, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) AS mjesec,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime) AS godina, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) AS sat, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime) AS minute, EXTRACT(SECOND FROM datetime) AS sekunde FROM cutoffs WHERE id=". $redCutoff["cutoff_id"] ."");
    $datum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datum_query);

    if($datum["mjesec"] == 1){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Jan " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 2){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Feb " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 3){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Ma " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 4){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Apr " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 5){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Mei " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 6){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Jun " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 7){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Jul " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 8){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Aug " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 9){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Sep " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 10){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Okt " . $datum["godina"];
    }elseif($datum["mjesec"] == 11){
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Nov " . $datum["godina"];
    }else{
        $datumLevering = $datum["dan"] . ". Dec " . $datum["godina"];
    }
    $leveringVrijeme = $datum["sat"] . "u" . $datum["minute"];
    $leveringDateandTime =  $datumLevering . "-" . $leveringVrijeme;
```

I store in my database a datetime field and when i want to get result if value of the field is for example 2015-08-19 20:***10***:00, i get good result in **$leveringVrijeme** (20u10), but if the value is for example 2015-08-19 20:***00***:00, then i get in **$leveringVrijeme** (20u0).

Why i do not get the other 0?

Comment: it seems you are getting an integer (0) ratehr than a string (00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract` returns the values as numbers.  For your formatting purposes, you seem to want zero-padded strings.  So, instead of `extract`, use `date_format()`:

```
select date_format(datetime, '%d') as day,
       date_format(datetime, '%m') as mon,
       date_format(datetime, '%Y') as year,
       date_format(datetime, '%H') as hours,
       date_format(datetime, '%i') as minutes,
       date_format(datetime, '%s') as seconds
```

This retrieves them as zero-padded strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider casting it to string literal or `VARCHAR` using `CAST` like

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM datetime) AS dan, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) AS mjesec,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime) AS godina, 
    CAST(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) AS VARCHAR) AS sat, 
    CAST(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime) AS VARCHAR) AS minute, 
    CAST(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM datetime) AS VARCHAR) AS sekunde 
    FROM cutoffs 
    WHERE id=". $redCutoff["cutoff_id"] ."");
```